# Does UserDefaults return default value or nil when inaccessible?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, ios13, data-protection

I am working in an iOS project which is facing issues accessing `UserDefaults` value when file protection is enabled. There are couple of posts in Apple communities regarding `UserDefaults` inaccessibility issue. Some of the discussions are,

1. [UserDefault Getting NULL](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28030)
2. [NSUserDefault is lost](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/135342)

This is really frustrating for me as my app used to check Boolean value for key **FirstTimeAppLaunched** and based on the value it recreates `db encryption password` for my database. Due to the above mentioned issues, once the `UserDefault` is inaccessible my app is re-creating new password and eventually losts all data previously used by users using different password.

Now I am thinking to use integer status rather boolean hence I need to use,

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(["FirstTimeAppLaunched", 0]);
```

when the app starts. And after first launched I set it to 1 using,

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "FirstTimeAppLaunched");
```

In that case I need to be confirmed about,

**if standard `UserDefault` is inaccessible due to the above mentioned issues, is it guaranteed that the returned value for key `FirstTimeAppLaunched` will be `NULL` or the default value I registered using `UserDefaults.standard.register` method?**

Comment: Can't you use key chain to store db password and check if one exists?

Comment: I faced this issue previously, end up using sqlite to store the flag instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between scalar types (`Bool`, `Int`, `Double`) and objects.

The default values are:

- Key/value pairs are **not** registered

  - Objects are `nil`,
  - Scalar types are `false`, `0`, `0.0` if you use `bool(forKey`, `integer(forKey` and `double(forKey`.
- Key/value pairs are registered

  - The registered value is returned until the value is overwritten.

In your case you can use an unregistered `Bool` value if you use `bool(forKey` to read it.